# casting long to int

Tags: java, casting, long-integer

I have one variable which gets current time and stored in long. But I have to convert it to **int** as it is the requirement. So what i am doing is converting the val with (int) and storing inside the int.

```
Val = 1355399741522 (long)
Int Val = -1809346991 (after casting to int)

After Casting from int to long -> Val = -1809346991 //TESTED
```

Now my question is if I want to convert this int again back to long than definitely it will not going to work for me. **That i already tested.** But I want alternate solution for this.

**NOTE - I don't want to store long. As its the requirement. And I am using below function to convert the long to time**

```
public static String convertToTime(final long date) {
        String time = null;
        final SimpleDateFormat bartDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
        final SimpleDateFormat bartDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        final Date fomDat = new Date(date);
        final int hour = Integer.parseInt(bartDateFormat1.format(fomDat));
        final int min = Integer.parseInt(bartDateFormat2.format(fomDat));
        time = pad(hour) + ":" + pad(min);
        return time;
    }
```

If anyone has any idea please kindly guide me or provide any alternative.

Comment: Split the `long` and store it in two `int`s and concat them to restore? :| Not sure what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: `1355399741522` can't be stored in an int because it is too large (it is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE). What you are trying to achieve is not clear...

Comment: Your number is too big to store in an int. It seems to be the number of miliseconds from the epoch(1970). If you divide this by 1000, you get the number of seconds since 1970, this can be stored in an int (at least until 2038, where it will overflow). Is seconds resolution suitable for you ?

Comment: What *is* the requirement? I'm quite sure it *isn't* to "store a long as an int". In English, what are you trying to do?

Comment: This is simply NOT POSSIBLE. What does the lon value in your example indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When time is stored as an `int` it's usually in seconds because milli-seconds will not fit.  If you do this

```
long timeInMs = 1355399741522L;
int timeInSec = (int) (timeInMs / 1000); // now 1355399741
long timeInMs2 = timeInSec * 1000L; // now 1355399741000L
```

Comment: Get all the mileage you can out of this solution; it'll only work for another 25 years or so.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `long` that contains a value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and you cast it to an `int` and then back to a `long`, you won't get the original value back again.

If you have a "requirement" to do that, then your requirement is not implementable.  What you are trying to do is a mathematical impossibility.

(You should also consider the possibility that you have misunderstood the requirement ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the long to String and create an Integer(String) object. 
but since the Long.MAX_VALUE(2^63-1) is much more than the Integer.MAX_VALUE(2^31 - 1), you have to make a compromise on the length of the long variable if that exceeds the maximum length of the integer type.

Comment: but what happens during the compromise / overflow?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertToTime(final long date) {
        String time = null;
        final SimpleDateFormat bartDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m");
        time = bartDateFormat1.format( date );
        return time;
    }
```